# Snakemake: Wrapper command logging

Tags: snakemake

I fail to figure out how I can log the commands executed by a wrapper. Both "snakemake -p" and "snakemake -D" are not showing me the actual commands that were run.

What is the best approach for logging the commands created through a wrapper?

Cheers,
Seb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, currently, -p is indeed not propagated to scripts or wrappers. However, I have just changed that in the code, and the upcoming release 4.0 will give you what you want with snakemake -p.

Note that wrappers often do more than executing a single shell command. You can find the entire source code of a wrapper on the respective page in the wrapper description. E.g., see here for **bwa mem**: https://snakemake-wrappers.readthedocs.io/en/stable/wrappers/bwa/mem.html#code

Comment: I have a feeling the -p  is not working anymore for wrappers with 5.3.0? Any ideas how to trouble shoot a wrapper? How can I access the produced command/script by it?

Comment: Thanks for reporting. This should now be fixed again in the master branch and the next release.

Comment: Resurrecting this since it doesn't seem like `-p` is working for wrappers currently. Should it be? Is there another recommended way to check the resulting commands?

Comment: If a wrapper fails in the shell command, you should get it printed in the error message. Apart from that, you can always clone the wrapper repo, and point to the local clone with --wrapper-prefix git+file:///path/to/your/clone. Then, inside of the clone, just branch and add debug code to the respective wrapper.